# Why doesn't make.names() function keep the original names?

Tags: r, identifier, names, illegal-characters

I'm using the command make.names() to make the "row.names" of the first column of my matrix. But the problem is that some characters change.

Here is an example; assume that the first column which is going to be the row.name is named "levels"

```
> row.names    levels
  ig.yht       ig:yht
```

I want to keep all characters the same. but make.names() command changes some symbols like ":" to "."

This is the code I have run:

```
rownames(FRC)=make.names(FRC[,1],unique=TRUE)
```

`FRC` is the name of the matrix.

Comment: From [`?make.names`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.names.html): *"A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed by a number."* The colon is not legal in a "valid name".

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have to keep the names as they are. Do you have any suggestion, please?

Comment: Don't use `make.names`? Row names do not have the same constraints as column names (for which `make.names` is useful). Or do you have non-unique contents within `FRC[,1]`? (For that, consider [`make.unique`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.unique.html).)

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked :)

Comment: To help you find this next time ... many pages include a "See Also" section that references related functions, either due to dependency or different behaviors. In this case, if you look at `?make.names` looking to resolve this, you will see references to `'make.unique'`. Not all help pages include this or include everything, but it's a start.

Comment: Aha. I see that. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You're not really asking *"Why doesn't make.names() function keep the original names?"*, you're asking *"How do I read in my dataset where the rownames are syntactically invalid identifiers, and prevent `make.names` fixing them?"* (To which the answer is make sure the non-default option `check.names=F` is used). Can you edit your title?